# PHP 8.1: strftime() is deprecated

Tags: php

When upgrading to PHP 8.1, I got an error regarding "strftime".
How do I correct the code to correctly display the full month name in any language?

```
 $date = strftime("%e %B %Y", strtotime('2010-01-08'))
```

Comment: strftime and gmstrftime functions are deprecated in PHP 8.1 and later. see replacements: https://php.watch/versions/8.1/strftime-gmstrftime-deprecated

Comment: There is always great documentation on when they deprecate a function with new releases: https://php.watch/versions/8.1/strftime-gmstrftime-deprecated

Comment: How does using a deprecated function makes the question less valid?

Comment: Hi, how did you fix it? Which of the answers in this post did help you?

Comment: According to https://github.com/php/php-src/issues/11190 the deprecation of strftime() has nothing to do with threads and locales.

Answer (score 13):

To my dear and late strftime()... I found a way to adapt with IntlDateFormatter::formatObject and here is the link for the references to the schemas:

https://unicode-org.github.io/icu/userguide/format_parse/datetime/#date-field-symbol-table

... For those who want to format the date more precisely

```php
// "date_default_timezone_set" may be required by your server
date_default_timezone_set( 'Europe/Paris' );

// make a DateTime object 
// the "now" parameter is for get the current date, 
// but that work with a date recived from a database 
// ex. replace "now" by '2022-04-04 05:05:05'
$dateTimeObj = new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone('Europe/Paris'));

// format the date according to your preferences
// the 3 params are [ DateTime object, ICU date scheme, string locale ]
$dateFormatted = 
IntlDateFormatter::formatObject( 
  $dateTimeObj, 
  'eee d MMMM y à HH:mm', 
  'fr' 
);

// test :
echo ucwords($dateFormatted);

// output : Jeu. 7 Avril 2022 à 04:56
```

Comment: Finally I went a little deeper into the subject and it is better to let the native function manage things, I created a function for myself, maybe to improve but for my needs it covers all the cases, this function is here : 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72435485/php-intldateformatter-remove-day-from-the-date-format/72561375#72561375

Comment: There is a problem with accents. Try the date 2023-02-01 00:00:59 : you will have : Mercredi 1 FÃ©vrier 2023 00:00:59
How to solve this, please ?

Comment: add <meta charset="utf-8"> into the <head>..</head> and maybe too <html lang="fr"> on your html code or use a PHP function : ex. $dateFormatted = mb_convert_encoding($dateFormatted, "UTF-8");

Answer (score 8):

I've chosen to use [php81_bc/strftime](https://packagist.org/packages/php81_bc/strftime) composer package as a replacement.

Here the [documentation](https://github.com/alphp/strftime).

Pay attention that the output could be different from native `strftime` 'cause `php81_bc/strftime` uses a different library for locale aware formatting (ICU).

> Note that output can be slightly different between libc sprintf and this function as it is using ICU.

Answer (score 4):

The `strftime` is obsolete and `DateTime::format()` provide a quick replacement and `IntlDateFormatter::format()` provied a more sophisticated slution.

this links will be help you:

https://github.com/modxcms/revolution/issues/15864

https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/1cf4fb739f7a4fa8404a4c0958f13d04eae519d4/UPGRADING#L379-L381

https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php

Comment: `DateTime::format` cannot be used for that purpose as it only outputs English. See php.net doc under Notes.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [IntlDateFormatter class](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.intldateformatter.php). The class works independently of the locales settings. With a function like this

```
function formatLanguage(DateTime $dt,string $format,string $language = 'en') : string {
    $curTz = $dt->getTimezone();
    if($curTz->getName() === 'Z'){
      //INTL don't know Z
      $curTz = new DateTimeZone('UTC');
    }

    $formatPattern = strtr($format,array(
        'D' => '{#1}',
        'l' => '{#2}',
        'M' => '{#3}',
        'F' => '{#4}',
      ));
      $strDate = $dt->format($formatPattern);
      $regEx = '~\{#\d\}~';
      while(preg_match($regEx,$strDate,$match)) {
        $IntlFormat = strtr($match[0],array(
          '{#1}' => 'E',
          '{#2}' => 'EEEE',
          '{#3}' => 'MMM',
          '{#4}' => 'MMMM',
        ));
        $fmt = datefmt_create( $language ,IntlDateFormatter::FULL, IntlDateFormatter::FULL,
        $curTz, IntlDateFormatter::GREGORIAN, $IntlFormat);
        $replace = $fmt ? datefmt_format( $fmt ,$dt) : "???";
        $strDate = str_replace($match[0], $replace, $strDate);
      }

    return $strDate;
}
```

you can use format parameters like for datetime.

```
$dt = date_create('2022-01-31');
echo formatLanguage($dt, 'd F Y','pl');  //31 stycznia 2022
```

There are extension classes for DateTime that have such functions integrated as methods.

```
echo dt::create('2022-01-31')->formatL('d F Y','pl');
```

Comment: Is this answer as "sweet" as it can be?  Should we see a `preg_replace_callback()` used to eliminate some of the placeholder translations?  Does it need so many translations?

Answer (score -1):

I made a script that defines `strftime()` function if it does not exist. Note that this is solution for already existing programming codes which are based on `strftime()`. For new code works you should forget using `strftime()` function.

https://github.com/sunhater/strftime

Answer (score -2):

`strftime` is deprecated PHP 8.1, You can use `date` function.

```
$date = date("%e F Y", strtotime('2010-01-08'))
```

Comment: Note for users that are using `setlocale()` function: `date()` is only able to return month/day names in english, even if you changed your `setlocale()`

Answer (score -3):

Hey I have also experienced this issue as well so after some research on PHP's official documentation here what I found!
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php

They are saying that it is depricated and use `setlocale()` function
this also work same as `strftime()`.

For more information please visit official PHP docs of `setlocale()` https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php

Answer (score -4):

A quick and simple replacement for the deprecated function `strftime` can be following.

Instead of using (taking the sample from the question)

`$date = strftime("%e %B %Y", strtotime('2010-01-08'))`

convert that to:

`$date = date('d M Y', strtotime('2010-01-08')`

Comment: date() does not localize the output.

Comment: Downvoted because this doesn't answer the question of how to translate.